# Match any whole number followed by a specific value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, match

I have an object in javascript -:

```
var array = {"1":"John","2":"Caprio","3":"David","4":"Edward"}
```

I want to do this -:

```
var message = 'Wats up David#1. Are you with David#5 or Caprio#89'; 

$.each(array, function(key, value){
var matchMe=value+'#'+anywholenumber;                                                       
if(message.match(matcheMe))
{ 
var ge = new RegExp(matchMe, 'g'); 
message = message.replace(ge,'['+matchMe+']');
}                                });
```

How do i do it? Thanks a lot for help

Comment: So where's the array at, and what's in it ?

Comment: array is the variable `var array`

Comment: Just to be clear, `array` is an object here.

Comment: Oh sorry i just misspelled it, yes `array` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have would replace *every* number with the first element (john) if it were working.

I think you want this:

```
var arr = array("John","Caprio","David","Edward","Suzy");
var message = 'Wats up David#1. Are you with David#5 or Caprio#2'; 

for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp(i, 'g');
    message = message.replace(re, arr[i]);
}
```